# Exif image data?

Tags: publishing, templating, webdav

I see that Tridion preserves an image's Exif details (e.g. [example image](http://www.exiv2.org/sample.html)). For example using WebDAV I can see the original Exif values on the left are still available on the right.

[image: Exif data is preserved in the Content Manager]

This works for loading images in the Content Manager Explorer, using `Upload Multimedia`, or by WebDAV.

These values are also kept when publishing the original image, though I notice copies lose this "metadata." For example, we have an "Image Resize" Template Building Block in training that creates a separate variant image that has its own (blank) Exif data.

**Questions**:

- Is there a way to programatically set these values on publish?
- Also, any thoughts on how Exif are handled with Contextual Image Delivery?

I'd imagine we'd do *something* with AddBinary() at least for publishing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As EXIF data can only be defined for formats such as [JPEG and TIFF](http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000146.shtml) - the I guess creating the variant we are putting it into a graphics 'object' as we resize - which is essentially converting the image to a regular bitmap so you'd lose the EXIF meta.

You could perhaps [extract the EXIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649/how-to-get-the-exif-data-from-a-file-using-c-sharp) data prior to resizing (perhaps put this in the image metadata) and then re-apply after the resize process.

Answer (score 2):

**Q:** *Is there a way to programatically set these values on publish?*

**A:** Yes, but you need to do it either before the upload, or publish it as a variant using `AddBinary()` indeed. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226973/how-to-edit-exif-data-in-net for some details.

**Q:** *any thoughts on how Exif are handled with Contextual Image Delivery?*

**A:** I wouldn't know about that.